# @Scope("prototype") is not working in spring boot upgrade from version 2.1.7 RELEASE to 2.7.11 RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans, spring-bean

I have a bean annotated with @Scope("prototype"). It worked well with Spring boot  2.1.7 RELEASE. Spring created this bean only when requested from application context, but after upgrading to spring boot version 2.7.11 RELEASE the spring is trying to create bean even before it is requested(spring tries to create a bean at start up). I have tried @Lookup @Lazy and @Scope(value = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES) but nothings works. It seems prototype bean is not at all working.

```
    @Scope("prototype")
    @Bean
    public MyClass myBeanLoader(final DataSource ds){
       // some code
        return myclass;
    }

//trying to load bean at runtime,but bean is created even before below code. Ideally the bean should be created after below code.

DataSource ds=new DataSource();
appContext.getBean(MyClass.class,ds);
```